# Converting a measure to date for line chart in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to convert some measures that I have into dates for making a line chart. This is the data I have.
[[image: Tableau Data[1]]

I am trying to make a line chart out of this data. But I cannot put it under a date since there are no dates in the dimensions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to some how reshape this data to create a single date field. You can do that out of Tableau or perhaps use Tableau prep. Your underlying data source is likely to drive that decision, you don't mention anything about that in your question.

Edit from comments:

Connect to the spreadsheet in Tableau. In the Data Source window, where it shows you all of the data in a table, select the 4 fields starting with Tuition and Fees. Then click on the drop down and Pivot those fields.

That will create 2 new fields, Pivot Field Names and Pivot Field Values.

In your workbook create 2 new calculated fields:

```
[FeeYear]: LEFT(RIGHT([Pivot Field Names],7),4)
```

and

```
[FeeDate]: MAKEDATE(INT([FeeYear]),1,1)
```

You can use FeeDate as the x axis of your line chart. Pivot Field Values is the measure to use in your line chart.

Comment: My data is currently from here: https://public.tableau.com/s/sites/default/files/media/Resources/IPEDS_data.xlsx
hope this helps explain a bit more about the data.

Comment: I am trying to show the increase in cost of tuition and fees over the years for Geographic regions or states.